# C Bitwise, TRUNCATING zero's in hex. 0x15000000 -> 0x15 ??? HOW?

Tags: c++

Is this even at all possible?

How would I truncate zeros?

In the integer withOUT using any masking techniques (NOT ALLOWED: 0x15000000 & 0xff000000 like that.). And also WITHOUT any casting.

Comment: Do you mind if I ask why exactly you would want to truncate the right side?

Comment: Yes, please accept your favorite answers for all your questions.

Comment: Your question is a bit like "Write a C program without using braces." Even if this is possible, the obvious question is: Why without braces, erm, _masking_?

Answer (score 5):

Well, really, if you want to truncate the right side, the naive solution is:

```
uint input = 0x150000;
if(input)
{
    while(!(input & 0x01))  // Replace with while(!(input % 0x10)) if you are actually against masking.
    {
        input >>= 1;
    }
}

// input, here, will be 0x15.
```

Though, you can unroll this loop.  As in:

```
if(!(input & 0xFFFF)) { input >>= 16; }
if(!(input & 0x00FF)) { input >>= 8;  }
if(!(input & 0x000F)) { input >>= 4;  }  // Comment this line, down, if you want to align on bytes.
if(!(input & 0x0003)) { input >>= 2;  }  // Likewise here, down, to align on nybbles.
if(!(input & 0x0001)) { input >>= 1;  }
```

Comment: I would test for 0. Otherwise you may go into an infinite loop.

Comment: Not quite.  That would truncate the 1's.  while(!(input & 0x01))

Comment: Mmm.. technically that's a masking technique.

Comment: @Martin, True.  Though, I was in the midst of an edit saying that...  @indiv,  Very good.  Updated.

Comment: Souldn't you mask with 0xF and shift by 4 in your first example?

Comment: Only if he wanted to align on bytes.  He said, 'zeros,' which implies 'digits.'

Comment: He's showing numbers written in HEX and says he wants the trailing zeros removed. A HEX number ends in a zero if it is a multiple of 16. Being even is not sufficient for a trailing zero in HEX.

Comment: OK! FINE, Hence the Comment on how to ALIGN ON NYBLES!  Sheesh.

Answer (score 3):

One way to do it without *any* masking (assuming you want to truncate zero *bits*):

```
int input = 0x150000;
while (input && !(input%2))
    input >>= 1;
```

Here's a complete program which illustrates it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int input = 0;
    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Needs at least one parameter.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    input = atoi (argv[1]);
    printf ("%x -> ", input);
    while (input && !(input%2))
        input >>= 1;
    printf ("%x\n",input);
    return 0;
}
```

If you want to truncate zero *nybbles*, use:

```
while (input && ((input%16)==0))
    input >>= 4;
```

Comment: Kobayashi Maru - sometimes the only way to win the game is to change the rules :-)

Comment: I'd say that so far you're the only one that noticed that the question specified HEX and avoided any masking.  +1

Comment: I'd consider `input && !(input%2)` masking.

Comment: Oh, and what happens if I call your program like this: `pax_test blah`? (This question has a C++ tag, you know. Why not use streams?)

Comment: @sbi, the && and ! are logical, not bitwise so it's not masking. In addition, the % is a remainder operation, also not masking (I make no promises about what the compiler generates under the hood). As to the bad input, the *answer* is the while statements, not the supporting code - that's just for testing. You may as well comment on my indentation style for all the relevance it has to do with the question and answer.

Comment: @Pax: I'm really sorry if I offended you. I didn't mean to. I agree with your answer regarding the masking. That was a brainfart of mine. I disagree with your answer regarding `atoi`. IMO, using `atoi` leads to the dark side: `assert(atoi("0")!=atoi("blah"));` And having taught C++ for years - with some of the students later becoming fellow workers - I have learned the hard way that one should do it Right(TM) even in the smallest example.

Comment: No offence taken, @sbi, the medium we use doesn't always allow for full flow of communication. I don't usually rely on atoi except for quick and dirty stuff - in fact, part of my vast library of tools consists of a "better" atoi that checks the entire string is numeric. But if I were to worry about all those sort of things here on SO, my answers would become even *more* lengthy and incomprehensible :-)

Answer (score 2):

John Gietzen's answer is my favourite, but for fun, it can actually be done without a loop!

If you know how many trailing zeros there are, then you can just shift right that number of bits.  There are a number of techniques for finding the number of bits.  See the few sections following the linear algorithm here: http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ZerosOnRightLinear.

Comment: I have it without a loop at the bottom. ;) Nice link, though.

Answer (score 1):

Divide by 16 (one nybble or hex digit's worth), as long as it's a multiple of 16:

```
if ( number )
    while ( number % 16 == 0 )
        number /= 16;
```

Of course, you can drop the initial test for zero if you know you'll never that as input.

Comment: @sellibitze:  Not so.  The first line guards against that.

Comment: Unless another thread comes in and changes it to 0 between the if and the while. Maybe we should mutex-protect the whole thing :-)

Answer (score 1):

Does this count as masking?

```
unsigned int truncate(unsigned int input)
{
    while (input != 0 && input % 0x10 == 0)
    {
        input /= 0x10;
    }

    return input;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to convert the int to a byte, so you are now down to 8 bits, so not everything is truncated, necessarily, but it would have fewer zeroes.

I am hoping this isn't for homework, but because I fear it is, giving you all the code would not be fair.

Comment: This is out of my own interest.

Answer (score 0):

Shift right with 24. Make sure your variable is unsigned.

Comment: Unfortunately, the input isn't always exactly a particular number of 00's . sometimes 4, sometimes 6, sometimes 2. 

How to trim without any predicting?

Comment: The question didn't mention an arbitrary number of zeros. Badly phrased questions get stupid answers.